# Importing Netbeans project from 6.9 to 7.1

Tags: grails, netbeans, import, project

I'm currently working on a project using netbeans 6.9 and grails 1.3. I'm trying to switch my development to another machine with netbeans 7.1. I tried copying the whole directory but netbeans keeps asking for a "project folder" and when I select my app folder it is not recognized as such. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the Netbeans Plugins panel (Tools -> Plugins), select the 'Available Plugins' tab and install the 'Groovy and Grails' plugin. After the install and a Netbeans restart, you should be able to open the existing project folder into Netbeans with no problem.